# Spark Standalone Mode: Worker not starting properly in cloudera

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, apache-spark, cloudera-manager

I am new to the spark, After installing the spark using parcels available in the cloudera manager.

I have configured the files as shown in the below link from cloudera enterprise:

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Ent/4.8.1/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cmig_spark_installation_standalone.html

After this setup, I have started all the nodes in the spark by running /opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK/lib/spark/sbin/start-all.sh. But I couldn't run the worker nodes as I got the specified error below.

```
[root@localhost sbin]# sh start-all.sh
org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master running as process 32405. Stop it first.
root@localhost.localdomain's password: 
localhost.localdomain: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /var/log/spark/spark-root-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-localhost.localdomain.out
localhost.localdomain: failed to launch org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker:
localhost.localdomain:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.10)
localhost.localdomain:      at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.10)
localhost.localdomain: full log in /var/log/spark/spark-root-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-localhost.localdomain.out
localhost.localdomain:starting org.apac
```

When I run jps command, I got:

```
23367 Jps
28053 QuorumPeerMain
28218 SecondaryNameNode
32405 Master
28148 DataNode
7852 Main
28159 NameNode
```

I couldn't run the worker node properly. Actually I thought to install a standalone spark where the master and worker work on a single machine. In slaves file of spark directory, I given the address as "localhost.localdomin" which is my host name. I am not aware of this settings file. Please any one cloud help me out with this installation process. Actually I couldn't run the worker nodes. But I can start the master node.

Thanks & Regards,
 bips

Comment: you should give us the full log (/var/log/spark/spark-root-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-localhost.localdomain.out).
First I saw the: "root@localhost.localdomain's password: " which seems to indicate that you did not setup passwordless ssh connections as stated in the page you give form cloudera.
Moreover, when the log says "org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master running as process 32405. Stop it first.", well, just do it: "stop-master.sh && start-master.sh && start-worker.sh"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please notice error info below:

```
localhost.localdomain:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.10)
```

I met the same error when I installed and started Spark master/workers on CentOS 6.2 x86_64 after making sure that **libgcj.x86_64** and **libgcj.i686** had been installed on my server, finally I solved it. Below is my solution, wish it can help you.

It seem as if your JAVA_HOME environment parameter didn't set correctly.
Maybe, your JAVA_HOME links to system embedded java, e.g. java version "1.5.0".
 
Spark needs java version >= 1.6.0. If you are using java 1.5.0 to start Spark, you will see this error info.
Try to export JAVA_HOME="your java home path", then start Spark again.